# Merging a long JSON with another using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I need to do some CURLs from which I'm building one output JSON. This is how I managed to perform a merge using a function:

```
...
ADDITIONALJSONDATA="{\"$DATATYPE\" : "$DATA"}" 
MERGEDENTRY=$(echo $SOURCE | jq --argjson json "$ADDITIONALJSONDATA" '. += $json' | tr -d '\r\n')
 ...
```

It seems when JSON inside `$DATA` is big enough then I'm getting `Argument list too long` error. Is it possible (in a nice way) to treat JSON to merge as a single argument here?

Comment: As an aside -- all-caps variable names are in a reserved namespace; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html for POSIX guidelines, specifying that all-caps names are used for shell and environment variable names with meaning to the shell and POSIX-defined utilities, whereas lowercase names are reserved for applications and guaranteed not to conflict.

Comment: Also, much better to use `jq -c` to tell jq not to put extra whitespace in to begin with rather than trying to use `tr` to take it out after-the-fact. You might also want the `-j` argument to remove trailing whitespace, though this isn't always pertinent in a command substitution since those remove a trailing newline if one exists anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

1. If, as seems to be the case here, you already have $DATA and $DATATYPE, there is no need for ADDITIONALJSONDATA
2. In general, using `tr -d '\r\n'` here is very bad practice, e.g. because it could scrunch 1 and 2 together to make 12

Hopefully the following will meet your requirements:

```
MERGEDENTRY=$(jq -c --arg TYPE "$DATATYPE" --slurpfile A <(printf '%s\n' "$DATA") '
  . += {($TYPE): $A[0]}' <<< "$SOURCE")
```

(We need to use `$A[0]` here because "slurping" puts $DATA into an array.)

Comment: I'm getting `Bad JSON in --slurpfile A /proc/5992/fd/63: Could not open /proc/5992/fd/63: No such file or directory` Can MINGW64 and WinOS be a reason for that?

This is the SOURCE:
`{
 "id": "devlocal",
 "name": "devlocal",
...}`

This is the DATA:
`[{
  "username": "52352",
  "enabled": true,
  },
..]`

Comment: Can you test whether process substitution is working without using jq? Have you tried putting $DATA into a file so you can check the jq command without using process substitution?

Answer (score 1):

You could use process substitution and `--slurpfile` option to solve your issue:

```
MERGEDENTRY=$(echo "$SOURCE" | jq --slurpfile json <(printf '%s\n' "$ADDITIONALJSONDATA") '. += $json[0]' | tr -d '\r\n')
```

As per Charles' suggestion, we can simplify further by using `<<<` instead of `echo "$SOURCE" | ...`:

```
MERGEDENTRY=$(jq --slurpfile json <(printf '%s\n' "$ADDITIONALJSONDATA") '. += $json[0]' <<< "$SOURCE" | tr -d '\r\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it far easier:
`MERGEDENTRY=${source::-1}","\"$data_type\"":"$data","`
And then just keep in mind we need to end JSON payload properly by replacing `'` by `}`.

I can do this as I'm always adding new JSON payload at the end of existing one.